# Problem debug Blazor Webassembly after VS 2022 17.6 update

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

After updating VS 2022 to version 17.6 this morning, I cannot run my Blazor Webassembly project with debug. I have the launchSettings.json configured to "launchBrowser : true", the same as before the update and when I launch my app with debug I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')    at g.launchRoot (c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\preview\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\jsdiagnostics\debugger\debugAdapter\out\src\vsDebugServer.js:86:45)    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Only happens with Chrome and Edge and only when "launchBrowser : true". It work when this config is disabled and I access directly to the localhost.

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: reboot pc - sometimes process is still in memory and throws errors like that, also try run as admin visual studio and check if anything else

Comment: Already tried it, no success. The first run gives me the same error.

Comment: Don't install preview versions on a machine you need to get your job done.  The only guarantees you get is that it is buggy and they'll be waiting for your bug report.  SO is not the right place, nothing we can do to fix those bugs.  Use the "rollback update" feature to try to get the machine in proper shape again.

Comment: Thanks  @HansPassant, rollback update to previous version of Visual Studio did the trick. Thanks for the tip about preview versions os VS too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, this is a known issue with 17.6.0 Preview 1.0 and is fixed in Preview 2.0 which is pending.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-launch-Chrome-as-Debug-target/10286069?q=%5BVisual+Studio+2022+version+17.6+Preview+1%5D&sort=votes

There is no known workaround from the development team.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround the issue.
If you uncheck JavaScript in the Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General --> Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome, Edge, IE) it will run. Obviously, you won't be able to debug JS while doing it.
Hopefully the fix will be out soon.